# Stages where a https connection can fail

Tags: https

What is the *latest* stage, where a https connection can fail (i.e. the user demanding a https version gets a browser warning that the site is not secure since no https available)?

- beginning of connection, since the browser and server must establish a communication that is not available via the demanded https address?  - or
- (at least in case "https" was not directly typed as the requested URL and https is demanded by the browser/addon): at the stage where the server already has made some connection, has detected the browser, and decides what to do next, what browser/device/screen size specific content version and if/what encryption is available?

Comment: What do you mean by "HTTPS version"? The TLS version? Or the HTTP version?

Comment: Sorry for being imprecise. The encrypted conection you would expect when typing https:\\somedomain.tld. Will edit to make this clearer.